# How to create a stacked BarChart with custom bar origins as function?

Tags: charts

I want to create a simple stacked bar chart where the bars start a custom y-axis point and end at another y-axis point.

So far I have:

```
BarChart[{{2, 4}, {-2, 6}}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

which gives:

[image: Stacked bar chart]

However, I want a single bar on the left that originates at 2 and goes up to 4, and on the right a bar that starts at -2 and goes up to 6.

How can I achieve this? I also experimented around with the `ChartElementFunction` but I can not find how to specify a starting point of the bar.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is documented or not. You can pass additional arguments to the `ChartElementFunction` like this:

```
r[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, y_, {origin_}] :=
                           Rectangle[{xmin, ymin + origin}, {xmax, ymax + origin}]

BarChart[{{1} -> 1, {1} -> 2, {2} -> 3}, ChartElementFunction -> r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**edit**

Perhaps more elegant and somewhat more obscure:

```
r[a_, _, {origin_}] := Rectangle @@ Transpose[a + {0, origin}]
```

Comment: Ah, now this is great. Didn't know I can pass meta data into the element function as a rule. Thanks very much!

Comment: me too (missing something*)

Comment: @Kuba He! :D ...

Comment: Very nice, you can write even `{1 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 3 -> 3}`!

Comment: and `{2, 3, 4} -> 1` for a common origin :)

Comment: @ybeltukov Yup. The syntax I used was intended for this `BarChart[{{1, 2} -> 1, {1} -> 2, {2} -> 3}, ChartElementFunction -> r,
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]` , but then I decided for a the simpler example

Answer (score 1):

**Charting`RangeBarChart**

The undocumented function `` Charting`RangeBarChart `` does exactly what is required. It takes the same options as `BarChart`.

```
Charting`RangeBarChart[{{2, 4}, {-2, 6}},  
  ChartElementFunction->"GlassRectangle", ChartStyle->97, ChartLabels->{"A","B"}]
```

[image]

```
Charting`RangeBarChart[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {20, 2}], 
  ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle-> 97, 
  ChartLabels -> CharacterRange["A","T"]]
```

[image]

The same result can be obtained using a custom `ChartElementFunction` as in belisarius's answer. However, this function needs to be modified to work properly with a non-default `BarOrigin`. `` Charting`RangeBarChart `` takes care of necessary changes automatically. For example, in the first example above, with the options `BarOrigin -> Left` and `BarOrigin -> Right` we get

[image] [image]

The disadvantage of this alternative is that it works only for single data set of pairs. With multiple data sets, using a custom `ChartElementFunction` with appropriate modifications to account for the `BarOrigin` setting seems to be the only way. The function `ceF` in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141072/125) in a closely related Q/A does exactly that.

**See also:** [closely related Q/A: Floating Bar Chart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136512/125)